# how to create session in laravel 5.4 using laravel auth module

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4

how to set session in laravel 5.4 using laravel builtand Auth

**php artisan make:auth;**
when you run this command and it create complete signup and login process with view but it doesn't set session when user login. Can any body guide me how can i create session for login user ?

Comment: It does create a session

Comment: Are your protected routes within the web middleware?

Comment: no @SimonR m using middleare in my controller constructot

Comment: yes it create but how can i access that session in my controller @SapneshNaik ?

Comment: Search laravel http:session

Comment: thank you @SapneshNaik i got the solution
use this use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
than u can get all detail by this way
Auth::user();